# Windows command forfiles to copy subdirectories

Tags: windows, copy, command, xcopy

Using the forfiles Windows command, I wnat to copy a directory and every subdirectory. To do so, I´ve tried this:

```
forfiles /S /P  %myDirectoryPath% /C "CMD /C xcopy @path %NewPath% /Y /V /E"
```

But all files included in the subdirectories are copied in the same folder as the files of the main directory.

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `xcopy` to copy the directory tree

```
xcopy %myDirectoryPath% %NewPath% /t /e
```

Alternatively use `robocopy`

```
robocopy %myDirectoryPath% %NewPath% /e /create
```

Comment: /T should not be used, because in that case files wouldn´t  be copied; and /E should, because I also want to copy empty subdirectories :)

Comment: Ah right, I couldn't remember if /E would copy the directory structure :)